# What third party Speedlites work best with Canon?

Tags: canon, flash, third-party, hotshoe-flash

I am currently picking out a flash (speedlite) for Canon XSI. There is a number of third party flashes available from manufacturers other than Canon. They all claim to be Canon compatible but I have my doubts. I don't think any of those flash units work as great as ones made by Canon. I would like to know your opinion on the subject based on your expertise; what brands, models of third party speedlites work the best with Canon?

The most important features for me, that the flash must support are auto mode, zooming and e-ttl. For comparison it should be close in features to [Speedlite 430EX II](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/speedlite_flash_lineup/speedlite_430ex_ii)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sigma flashes will do as claimed, so I think you're safe there. The only downside, from my experience, is that the interface for them is less then stellar. However, other than that, the flashes are very good.

Another, which is a cut above Sigma, is Metz. If Metz has claimed support for Canon, the flash will do what is advertised for it, the company has a long history and produces good gear.

So, caveat time, I don't shoot Canon, I shoot Pentax. However, I have a Sigma flash and a Metz ring flash and both work great for me. So, I am extrapolating the experience there, but given that, I have little reason to doubt either. Pentax is a lesser known quantity versus Nikon or Canon, so if they got P-TTL working, I'd imagine that the similar from the big two were less of a problem.

Comment: Known quality of a system does not necesarrily mean its TTL protocols can be easily and reliably reverse-engineered. However, I'd be surprised if Sigma or Metz sold you a flash and it wouldn't work w/ Canon XSi. What can happen though is that you will buy a Canon master flash five years from now and it will work with 430EX II flawlessly, but your off-brand flash unit will need some kind of firmware upgrade.

Comment: This is a point in favor of Metz over Sigma, by the way, because most Metz models can be upgraded by the end user via a USB interface.

Comment: The "good" brands of third-party TTL flashes are generally excellent, but they're not where you'd go looking if you want to save a buck or two. Particularly in the case of Metz and Quantum, they usually offer power and features that the camera-brand flashes don't, and you *will* pay for the quality and functionality you get.

Comment: @Stan - I was a bit surprised at how reasonable Metz was, the ring flash I bought was less expensive than the Pentax option.

Comment: And in the US, we're paying inflated prices for Metz. In the EU, they're even more so. (Dunno about up there in Canada!)

Comment: Canada's no great shakes either (at least at Vistek and Henry's, and if I recall correctly, Carsand-Mosher in Halifax) but there are Metz units that are relatively reasonable -- the ringlight being among them. I still automatically think of the 45 series when the name Metz runs through my mind, though.

Comment: @mattdm - I suspect the price is inflated, but apparently not as much as Pentax's price was... As an added bonus, the Metz ring flash supports the TTL functions of Canon and Nikon, so it's a keeper for me no matter what.